# Preimage of a function

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

I'm having difficulties with the notion of preimage, specifically with this example:

Let $A$ be a subset of $[0, 1]$. We define

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x \in A;  \\ -x, & x \in [0, 1] \setminus A. \end{cases}$$

It is said that the premimage of $[0, 1]$ is equal to $A$. I don't understand why. I've read the definition of the preimage of a set several times and I understand it, but this example still does not make sense to me. I don't even understand what the function looks like.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The preimage of $A$ should be $A$ in this case.

Comment: @Bye_World Oh! I've made a typo. The correct sentence is "the preimage of [0, 1] is $A$".

Comment: The pre-image of [0,1] is actually A U [0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ takes $f(0)=0$ and $f(a)=a$ for $a\in A$ and $f(b)=-b$ for all $b\notin A$.

Actually, the ultiamte answer is that the preimage of $[0,1]$ along $f$ is $A\cup\{0\}$.

In elementary words, the required preimage $f^{-1}([0,1])$ is the set of those points $x$ of the domain of $f$ that satisfy $f(x)\in [0,1]$.

Now the domain is $[0,1]$ -- you can read it from the definition of $f$. 
And if $x\in A$ or $x=0$ then we will have $f(x)=x$ which is $\in [0,1]$. 
While, if $x\notin A$ and $x>0$, we will have $f(x)=-x<0$ which is $\notin [0,1]$.

All in all, $f^{-1}([0,1]) = A\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: This makes perfect sense now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The preimage of [0,1] are those mapped to themselves (as opposed to negative values) . Negative values are not between 0 and 1.